# Find transition in a signal and threshold (using Octave)

Tags: matlab, image-processing, signal-processing, octave, threshold

I have this detect transitions in this image (Iclock):
[image]

```
[cy, cx] = size(Iclock);
meanclock = zeros(1,cx);
for i = 1:cx

   meanclock(i) = mean(Iclock(:,i));
end
x = [1:cx];
c=polyfit(x',meanclock',2);

for i = 1  : cx

splineclock(i) = c(1,1)*(i)^2 + c(1,2)*i + c(1,3) ;
end
for i = 1:cx

        if meanclock(i) > splineclock(i)
            meanclock(i) = 255;
        else
           meanclock(i) = 0;
    endif
endfor
```

to do this i mean all the columns and interp the signal with a quadratic spline.
I can threshold the signal and get a square wave.
[image]

This does not work fine because the light distribution does not follow a quadratic path and also it does not consider the image distortion.
The result is not good enough.
[image]

Do you have in mind any other solution to help me please?
thanks

Comment: You have almost spelled you the next thing that I would try: Distorted image? Undistort it. If you can't because you can't calibrate the camera, then instead apply this to each of the rows of the image independently. Light is not a quadratic path? then use some other path? use higher order splines (but don't go too high, as you may overfit). However, I am not entirely convinced that this second thing is really a problem.

Comment: Undistort the image is not an available in this case. I wanted to try not to use higher order splines but adaptive method (like look at the difference between local maxima and minima)

Comment: Sure thats OK, but try to do it each row, that will already give you a much better solution I suspect. In fact, you need to do it if you want to account for the distortion

Comment: IMO, undistorting is complete overkill.

Comment: What is wrong with your result ? Seems perfect.

Comment: I don't think it's right to threshold with a quadratic spline if the signal it isn't

Comment: There is nothing wrong with that. What matters is to have an intermediate value, which is well achieved here. You might complain that this is not "accurate", but the edge you want to find are not regular anyway.

Comment: By the way, what you want to achieve is unclear. You ask for "transition in a signal", but this is an image.

Comment: yes sorry for the misunderstanding, I talked about a signal because i was thinking about the mean output

Comment: @GabrieleTordi: so I still don't know what you want to do and why you don't like your result.

Answer (score 2):

Your idea of estimating the illumination by model fitting is not so bad. For similar images, a parabolic profile should be good enough.

Alternatively, you can estimate the illumination by lowpass filtering in the horizontal direction. Make sure to crop out the white borders.

[image]